# Approved inappropriate Edit

Tags: discussion

@Jai and @Rama

You guys has done very good jobs in review queues That I appreciate,

But some time I notice that you guys just approves Inappropriate edits just like below

please take a time and then approve or rejects Edits

In below edit Editor removes code formatting and added wrong things that is inappropriate as grammar like editor removes capital `I` and added `i`

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/135698

Comment: I carefully checked and review edit and approved.  I fell he was added code indent. It is my error. Next time i will check more and approve. Thanks for info.  +1 :)

Comment: Thanks @RamaChandranM , and I must say you are doing very good job at review queue, keep doing it

Comment: Thanks for appreciation  :)

Comment: @RamaChandranM Please check  edits carefully , [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/136120) is one more example of your Inappropriate approval

Comment: I think I have to ignore code indent edit. I am missing something for approval for code indent. anyway, i will take care.